# Insert data into sql database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem getting the values from my form and passing it to the controller.

AddUser.cshtml

```
@model SecureMedi.Models.Users

<form asp-controller="Index" asp-action="AddUser" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username">Username</label>
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <!-- / form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Role">Username</label>
        <input asp-for="Role" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <!-- / form-group -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
</form>
<!-- / form -->
```

UsersDAL.cs (Data access layer)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SecureMedi.Models;

namespace SecureMedi.DAL {
    public class UsersDAL {
        public void Insert(Users u) {
            string connectionstring = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE USER {0} WITHOUT LOGIN", u.Username), conn);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(String.Format("ALTER ROLE {1} ADD MEMBER {0}", u.Username, u.Role), conn);

            try {
                conn.Open();

                using(conn) {
                    cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd2.Transaction = cmd.Transaction;
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd2.Transaction.Commit();
                }
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Users.cs (Model)

```
namespace SecureMedi.Models {
    public class Users {
        public string Username {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Role {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using nmvs_db.dal;
using nmvs_module;
using nmvs_module.util;
using SecureMedi.Models;
using SecureMedi.DAL;

namespace SecureMedi.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult AddUser(Users u)
        {
            UsersDAL ud = new UsersDAL();            
            ud.Insert(u);
            return View(u);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am facing two problems:

1) Whenever I navigate to `/AddUser` in my browser the `AddUser` method is called automatically. Instead, I would like to call `AddUser` method only when the `form` button is clicked.

2) Since `AddUser` is called (point 1) automatically the values I am retrieving from `u.Username` and `u.Role` is `null.`

For debugging purposes, if I modify my controller method like following:

```
public ActionResult AddUser(Users u) {
    if (u.Username == null)
        u.Username = "testuser";
    if (u.Role == null)
        u.Role = "SecureMediUsers";
    UsersDAL ud = new UsersDAL();
    ud.Insert(u);
    return View(u);
}
```

The only values which are passed in the DAL are the hardcoded values of `Username` and `Role` as shown above, where I want those values to be fetched from the `form` input values.

Comment: You method need to be decorated with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have tried that but I don't see the page being loaded due to 404 HTTP request not found error.

Comment: You also need a `public ActionResult AddUser() { return View(); }` method for the GET call

Comment: Yeah, I need to make a `GET` call too before I post some action. By the way, how would I return to another route after the POST call is made using `[HttpPost] AddUser()` method? I also like you to post this as an answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need separate GET and POST methods. The GET will be

```
[HttpGet] // this attribute is optional since its the default
public ActionResult AddUser()
{
    var model = new Users();
    return View(model);
}
```

and method you currently have needs to be marked with the `HttpPostAttribute`. In addition, you should be checking if `ModelState` is invalid, and if so, return the view immediately so the user can correct validation errors, and if not, save and then redirect.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(Users u)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(u);
    }
    UsersDAL ud = new UsersDAL();            
    ud.Insert(u);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // redirects to ../Home/Index
}
```

You should also consider adding validation attributes (e.g. a `[Required]` attribute assuming the values of the properties cannot be `null`), and add the validation message placeholders in your view for both client and server side validation (refer [Introduction to model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation)).

As as side note, your model describes as single User so the class should be `public class User` (not plural)

Comment: Thanks, I will hook up the validations.

Answer (score 0):

change the asp-controller="Index" to asp-controller="**Home**"

Comment: You are right in a way but that doesn't solve the asked problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using temp code to get the controller working but dont forget to protect yourself from SQL injection, and rolling back of transactions incase of faliure.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE USER {0} WITHOUT LOGIN", u.Username), conn);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(String.Format("ALTER ROLE {1} ADD MEMBER {0}", u.Username, u.Role), conn);
```

Example of loading an SqlCommand with SqlParameterCollection: (Not an ASP.NET project)

"nErrorMsg" is a paramater given to the encasing method:

```
try
  {
    nErrorMsg = nErrorMsg.Truncate(2000);

    using (SqlConnection sqlErrorLogConn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnString.ErrorLogConn))
    {
      try
      {
        sqlErrorLogConn.Open();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error whilst opening the connection with the database - (WriteToErrorLog)", "Connection Error", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
      }

      using (SqlCommand sqlErrorLogCommand = sqlErrorLogConn.CreateCommand())
      {
        string sqlCommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Error_Log] (Description,LoggedAt,ComputerName) VALUES (@Description,@LoggedAt,@ComputerName);");

        sqlErrorLogCommand.CommandText = sqlCommandText;
        sqlErrorLogCommand.Prepare();

        sqlErrorLogCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", nErrorMsg);
        sqlErrorLogCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedAt", DateTime.Now);
        sqlErrorLogCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComputerName", Environment.MachineName);

        sqlErrorLogCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error whilst communicating with the database: " + ex.ToString(), "Connection Error", 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
```